# If user has no access to email how to give them a temp password?

Tags: users, password

In Craft 2.3 admins aren't able to edit users passwords. So I'm wondering if they have no access to email how can we give them a temporary password?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can "Copy password reset URL" and give it to them via some other means (IM, etc.).

[image]

Comment: Good to know, Brad!